# Why does the absence of an error in Laravel Blade $errors array break my JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, forms, laravel, validation

I have a `Laravel` `Blade` file where I want to know about errors in the `name`, `email` or `message` fields.  [The has method may be used to determine if any error messages exist for a given field](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation).  I have a `JavaScript` function `indicateErrorBox` that adds some `CSS` classes to the form.

It works perfectly if **ALL** the fields have errors but if one or more doesn't, the code doesn't run.  It just seems to do nothing.

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  if ({{$errors->has('name')}}) {
    indicateErrorBox("name");
  }
  if ({{$errors->has('email')}}) {
    indicateErrorBox("email");
  }
  if ({{$errors->has('message')}}) {
    indicateErrorBox("message");
  }
};
</script>
```

I'm clearly doing something wrong.  Can anybody spot my error?

Comment: Should be easy to debug yourself by looking at the generated source browser sees and looking in browser console for errors thrown. What does generated source look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  @if ($errors->has('name'))
    indicateErrorBox("name");
  @endif
  @if ($errors->has('email'))
    indicateErrorBox("email");
  @endif
  @if ($errors->has('message'))
    indicateErrorBox("message");
  @endif
};
</script>
```

Comment: Check your generated source html/js to see what {{$errors->has(...)}} outputs. I would be surprised if it outputs true or false like your js code expects it to do. That's why I just used the blade if/else directives to call the JS functions directly if the conditions passed

Comment: Thanks for the explanation